# html canvas Drawing tool and highlight function

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I am a javascript function to copy paste an image from the clipboard to HTML canvas, futher i also have a function to let the user draw(highlight) on the image pasted on the canvas. However, the drawing tool function seems to override the copy paste function as it is anonymous. I need help to make these two functions operate.

this is my function to copy from clipboard.

```
function CLIPBOARD_CLASS(canvas_id, autoresize) {

    alert("BLAH");
    var _self = this;
    var canvas = document.getElementById(canvas_id);
    var ctx = document.getElementById(canvas_id).getContext("2d");
    var ctrl_pressed = false;
    var reading_dom = false;
    var text_top = 15;
    var pasteCatcher;
    var paste_mode;

    //handlers
    document.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
        _self.on_keyboard_action(e);
    }, false); //firefox fix
    document.addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
        _self.on_keyboardup_action(e);
    }, false); //firefox fix
    document.addEventListener('paste', function (e) {
        _self.paste_auto(e);
    }, false); //official paste handler

    //constructor - prepare
    this.init = function () {
        //if using auto
        if (window.Clipboard)
            return true;

        pasteCatcher = document.createElement("div");
        pasteCatcher.setAttribute("id", "paste_ff");
        pasteCatcher.setAttribute("contenteditable", "");
        pasteCatcher.style.cssText = 'opacity:0;position:fixed;top:0px;left:0px;';
        pasteCatcher.style.marginLeft = "-20px";
        pasteCatcher.style.width = "10px";
        document.body.appendChild(pasteCatcher);
        document.getElementById('paste_ff').addEventListener('DOMSubtreeModified', function () {
            if (paste_mode == 'auto' || ctrl_pressed == false)
                return true;
            //if paste handle failed - capture pasted object manually
            if (pasteCatcher.children.length == 1) {
                if (pasteCatcher.firstElementChild.src != undefined) {
                    //image
                    _self.paste_createImage(pasteCatcher.firstElementChild.src);
                }
            }
            //register cleanup after some time.
            setTimeout(function () {
                pasteCatcher.innerHTML = '';
            }, 20);
        }, false);
    }();
    //default paste action
    this.paste_auto = function (e) {
        paste_mode = '';
        pasteCatcher.innerHTML = '';
        var plain_text_used = false;
        if (e.clipboardData) {
            var items = e.clipboardData.items;
            if (items) {
                paste_mode = 'auto';
                //access data directly
                for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                    if (items[i].type.indexOf("image") !== -1) {
                        //image
                        var blob = items[i].getAsFile();
                        var URLObj = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
                        var source = URLObj.createObjectURL(blob);
                        this.paste_createImage(source);
                    }
                }
                e.preventDefault();
            }
            else {
                //wait for DOMSubtreeModified event
                //https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=891247
            }
        }
    };
    //on keyboard press - 
    this.on_keyboard_action = function (event) {
        k = event.keyCode;
        //ctrl
        if (k == 17 || event.metaKey || event.ctrlKey) {
            if (ctrl_pressed == false)
                ctrl_pressed = true;
        }
        //c
        if (k == 86) {
            if (document.activeElement != undefined && document.activeElement.type == 'text') {
                //let user paste into some input
                return false;
            }

            if (ctrl_pressed == true && !window.Clipboard)
                pasteCatcher.focus();
        }
    };
    //on kaybord release
    this.on_keyboardup_action = function (event) {
        k = event.keyCode;
        //ctrl
        if (k == 17 || event.metaKey || event.ctrlKey || event.key == 'Meta')
            ctrl_pressed = false;
    };
    //draw image
    this.paste_createImage = function (source) {
        var pastedImage = new Image();
        pastedImage.onload = function () {
            if (autoresize == true) {
                //resize canvas
                canvas.width = pastedImage.width;
                canvas.height = pastedImage.height;
            }
            else {
                //clear canvas
                ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            }
            ctx.drawImage(pastedImage, 0, 0);
        };
        pastedImage.src = source;
    };
}
```

This my drawing tool function

```
    if (window.addEventListener) {
    window.addEventListener('load', function () {
        var canvas, context, canvaso, contexto;

        // The active tool instance.
        var tool;
        var tool_default = 'line';

        function init() {
            // Find the canvas element.
            canvaso = document.getElementById('my_canvas_1');
            if (!canvaso) {
                alert('Error: I cannot find the canvas element!');
                return;
            }

            if (!canvaso.getContext) {
                alert('Error: no canvas.getContext!');
                return;
            }

            // Get the 2D canvas context.
            contexto = canvaso.getContext('2d');
            if (!contexto) {
                alert('Error: failed to getContext!');
                return;
            }

            // Add the temporary canvas.
            var container = canvaso.parentNode;
            canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
            if (!canvas) {
                alert('Error: I cannot create a new canvas element!');
                return;
            }

            canvas.id = 'imageTemp';
            canvas.width = canvaso.width;
            canvas.height = canvaso.height;
            container.appendChild(canvas);

            context = canvas.getContext('2d');

            // Get the tool select input.
            var tool_select = document.getElementById('dtool');
            if (!tool_select) {
                alert('Error: failed to get the dtool element!');
                return;
            }
            tool_select.addEventListener('change', ev_tool_change, false);

            // Activate the default tool.
            if (tools[tool_default]) {
                tool = new tools[tool_default]();
                tool_select.value = tool_default;
            }

            // Attach the mousedown, mousemove and mouseup event listeners.
            canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', ev_canvas, false);
            canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', ev_canvas, false);
            canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', ev_canvas, false);
        }

        // The general-purpose event handler. This function just determines the mouse 
        // position relative to the canvas element.
        function ev_canvas(ev) {
            if (ev.layerX || ev.layerX == 0) { // Firefox
                ev._x = ev.layerX;
                ev._y = ev.layerY;
            } else if (ev.offsetX || ev.offsetX == 0) { // Opera
                ev._x = ev.offsetX;
                ev._y = ev.offsetY;
            }

            // Call the event handler of the tool.
            var func = tool[ev.type];
            if (func) {
                func(ev);
            }
        }

        // The event handler for any changes made to the tool selector.
        function ev_tool_change(ev) {
            if (tools[this.value]) {
                tool = new tools[this.value]();
            }
        }

        // This function draws the #imageTemp canvas on top of #my_cavas_1, after which 
        // #imageTemp is cleared. This function is called each time when the user 
        // completes a drawing operation.
        function img_update() {
            contexto.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0);
            context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        }

        // This object holds the implementation of each drawing tool.
        var tools = {};

        // The drawing pencil.
        tools.pencil = function () {
            var tool = this;
            this.started = false;

            // This is called when you start holding down the mouse button.
            // This starts the pencil drawing.
            this.mousedown = function (ev) {
                context.beginPath();
                context.moveTo(ev._x, ev._y);
                tool.started = true;
            };

            // This function is called every time you move the mouse. Obviously, it only 
            // draws if the tool.started state is set to true (when you are holding down 
            // the mouse button).
            this.mousemove = function (ev) {
                if (tool.started) {
                    context.lineTo(ev._x, ev._y);
                    context.stroke();
                }
            };

            // This is called when you release the mouse button.
            this.mouseup = function (ev) {
                if (tool.started) {
                    tool.mousemove(ev);
                    tool.started = false;
                    img_update();
                }
            };
        };

        // The rectangle tool.
        tools.rect = function () {
            var tool = this;
            this.started = false;

            this.mousedown = function (ev) {
                tool.started = true;
                tool.x0 = ev._x;
                tool.y0 = ev._y;
            };

            this.mousemove = function (ev) {
                if (!tool.started) {
                    return;
                }

                var x = Math.min(ev._x, tool.x0),
                    y = Math.min(ev._y, tool.y0),
                    w = Math.abs(ev._x - tool.x0),
                    h = Math.abs(ev._y - tool.y0);

                context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

                if (!w || !h) {
                    return;
                }

                context.strokeRect(x, y, w, h);
            };

            this.mouseup = function (ev) {
                if (tool.started) {
                    tool.mousemove(ev);
                    tool.started = false;
                    img_update();
                }
            };
        };

        // The line tool.
        tools.line = function () {
            var tool = this;
            this.started = false;

            this.mousedown = function (ev) {
                tool.started = true;
                tool.x0 = ev._x;
                tool.y0 = ev._y;
            };

            this.mousemove = function (ev) {
                if (!tool.started) {
                    return;
                }

                context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

                context.beginPath();
                context.moveTo(tool.x0, tool.y0);
                context.lineTo(ev._x, ev._y);
                context.stroke();
                context.closePath();
            };

            this.mouseup = function (ev) {
                if (tool.started) {
                    tool.mousemove(ev);
                    tool.started = false;
                    img_update();
                }
            };
        };

        init();

    }, false);
}
```

This is my HTML CANVAS TAG

```
<canvas id="my_canvas_1" width="300" height="300" onclick="CLIPBOARD_CLASS('my_canvas_1',true);"></canvas>
```